# How do we perform custom operations on WindowedStream in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to perform some operations on a WindowedStream in Flink, say average.
But there are very limited operations available predefined like sum, min, max etc.

```
val windowedStream = valueStream
                          .keyBy(0)
                          .timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
                          .sum(2) //Change this to average?
```

Suppose I want to find the average, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink does not have a built-in function to compute the average on a `WindowStream`. You have to implement a custom `WindowFunction` for this.

The most efficient way is to implement a `ReduceFunction` that compute the count and sum of the value that you would like to average and a subsequent `WindowFunction` that takes the result of the `ReduceFunction` and computes the average. Using a `ReduceFunction` is more efficient, because Flink applies it directly on incoming values. Hence it aggregates values on the fly and does not collect them in the window. This significantlyy reduces the memory footprint of a window.

Since the output of a `ReduceFunction` has the same type as its input, you need to add a field for the count before applying the `ReduceFunction`.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
val valueStream: DataStream[(String, Double)] = ???

val r: DataStream[(String, Double)] = valueStream
  // append a 1L for counting
  .map(x => (x._1, x._2, 1l))
  // key and window stream
  .keyBy(0).timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
  .apply(
    // ReduceFunction (compute sum and count)
    (x: (String, Double, Long), y: (String, Double, Long)) => 
      (x._1, x._2 + y._2, x._3 + y._3),
    // WindowFunction
    (key, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[(String, Double, Long)], out: Collector[(String, Double)]) => {
      // get first (and only) value
      val x: (String, Double, Long) = input.toIterator.next
      // compute average as sum / count
      out.collect(x._1, x._2 / x._3)
    }
  )
```

Comment: There are not any examples or blog posts available for doing such tasks in Flink, I do not know how can I implement `ReduceFunction` and `WindowFunction`. Kindly can you share a example code?

Comment: OK, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, it is working after a little tweaking. Although, I am still very new to flink and could never have thought to write this up myself. Can you suggest me some references from where I can get hands on in Flink?

Comment: Have a look at the [free Flink training](http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training).

Comment: @FabianHueske: Can you please update this code in Java ??

Comment: Is there a reason to do it this way instead of using the [`aggregate`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/WindowedStream.html#aggregate-org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AggregateFunction-) function? The example implementation of `AggregateFunction` is a weighted average.